# I wants to display google banner ad in all the screens

Tags: android, ios, iphone, admob

What is the best way to do this?

1. Need to create separate instance/banner id for all the screen in google banner ad.
2. Create single instance/banner id and use the same id in all the screens for display google banner ad.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your choice
If you create a separate banner id for all the screens then you can easily track all the clicks and impressions for each banner in the admob/adsense console. Thats why it is advised to create separate id for each banner. Your revenue will be same if you have single id for all the banners or separate id for each banner.